# Why is this giving me a segmentation fault in c?

Tags: c

I have a pretty simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // argc is amount of elements that the user inputs, check if 1234 isn't in code
    if (strcmp(argv[argc-1],"1234" != 0)) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i],"-h")) {
            // do whatever
            printf("Hello world!");
        } else if (strcmp(argv[i],"-f")) {
            // argv[i+1] will be the file, print out the file to console
        } 
    } 
}
```

It allows the user to enter something, say `./my_kill -h 1234`. If 1234 isn't the last thing, it's supposed to just exit. Then in the for loop, if `-h` is used it prints hello world. For some reason it is giving me a segmentation fault and I don't understand why.

Comment: `strcmp(argv[argc-1],"1234" != 0)` - take a closer look.

Comment: Separate from your specific issue, you may consider using the getopt/getopt_long for handling your arguments.

Comment: Didn't the compiler warn you? That code should make it quite worried :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a parenthesis in the wrong position.

```
if (strcmp(argv[argc-1],"1234" != 0))
```

should be

```
if (strcmp(argv[argc-1],"1234") != 0)
```

Also, the first thing you should do is check if there is any information inside of argv.